# Utilisation of «Canvas» with NodeJS : «Cannot find module '../build/Release/canvas.node'»

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas

I've a problem by using «Canvas» librairy  with NodeJS. When I launch this command in terminal :

```html
node .
```

the terminal reply me this :

```html
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/canvas.node'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/nodejs-canvas/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
```

And I don't understand why.

Here is the *index.js* file :

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Canvas = require('canvas');

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
 console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
 const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'member-log');
 if (!channel) return;

 const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(700, 250);
 const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

 const background = await Canvas.loadImage('./wallpaper.jpg');
 ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

 ctx.strokeStyle = '#74037b';
 ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

 ctx.font = '28px sans-serif';
 ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
 ctx.fillText('Bienvenue,', canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 3.5);

 // Add an exclamation point here and below
 ctx.font = applyText(canvas, `${member.displayName}!`);
 ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
 ctx.fillText(`${member.displayName}!`, canvas.width / 2.5, canvas.height / 1.8);

 ctx.beginPath();
 ctx.arc(125, 125, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.clip();

 const avatar = await Canvas.loadImage(member.user.displayAvatarURL);
 ctx.drawImage(avatar, 25, 25, 200, 200);

 const attachment = new Discord.MessageAttachment(canvas.toBuffer(), 'welcome-image.png');

 channel.send(`Bienvenue sur le serveur, ${member}!`, attachment);
});
client.on('message', async message => {
 if (message.content === '!join') {
  client.emit('guildMemberAdd', message.member || await message.guild.fetchMember(message.author));
 }
});
client.login(SECRET TOKEN);
```

I have search help in Qwant, but i found nothing interressing.
Thanks a lot if you can help me.

> PS : I'm french  so sorry if i'm bad at english.

Comment: None of the snipets you provided are working :)

Comment: Did you try npm install?

Comment: yes, i use npm install canvas.

Comment: have you tried: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues/284#issuecomment-548563713

Comment: i have tried, and it is not work, but thanks to reply me.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas):

> Mac OS X v10.11+: If you have recently updated to Mac OS X v10.11+ and are experiencing trouble when compiling, run the following command: xcode-select --install. Read more about the problem on Stack Overflow. If you have xcode 10.0 or higher installed, in order to build from source you need NPM 6.4.1 or higher.

Comment: Hi !
Thanks to answer me ; but I am not using Mac, only Linux. I found a solution by using Jimp : https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp. Great tool !